# Как скачать (вырвать) шрифт с дизайна Figma?

Tags: шрифты, figma

Подскажите как в браузерной Figma скачать шрифт
В макете есть текст, но там своебразный шрифт, которого нет в Google Fonts
Мне нужно его как то скачать, это возможно?

Comment: @MaximLensky Да, установлен, но не знаю как им пользоваться

Comment: @MaximLensky сейчас посмотрю, попробую найти где это

Comment: выделите нужный текст - сбоку справа появится панель

Comment: @MaximLensky панель вижу, а missing fonts не могу найти

Comment: вообще этой опции нету в фигме ...шрифт должен быть на компе либо в fonts.google.com - если же нету то фигма будет писать что вы хотите редактировать шрифт которого нету

Comment: @MaximLensky вверху увидел кнопку 'A?' - missing fonts. Это оно? Случайно внёс изменения в дизайн, как вернуть назад?

Comment: я не знаю этого ...главное увидели - теперь скачайте на комп - установите шрифт, после того как сверстаете - подключите шрифт и всё